# ShellExecute for mailto: doesn't work with Google Chrome

Tags: c++, google-chrome, winapi, windows-shell, windows-explorer

I'm looking to open a default email program after a click on a hyperlink control in my app that links to an email address. For that I do the following:

```
//LPCTSTR addr = L"mailto:myaddress@gmail.com";
ShellExecute(hParentWnd, _T("open"), addr, NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

The approach above usually works by bringing up Outlook or Live Mail new email window with that address filled out in the "To:" field.

But when I have Google Chrome as my default web browser all I get is a blank Chrome browser window that simply shows my home page and nothing else.

So what am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Change `_T("open")` to `NULL`.  Not all apps use `"open"` as their default verb.  NULL forces the actual default to be used.

BTW, you should be using `TEXT()` instead of `_T()` when using `TCHAR` literals with the Win32 API.  `_T()` is meant for use with the C runtime library instead.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried it and it did the exact same thing -- got just a blank home page.

Comment: Then the problem is on Chrome's side, not your app.  Maybe it did not register itself with the `mailto` URL correctly, so it is not detecting the email address.  Either way, the problem is not on your end.